# TypeScript discriminated union cannot narrow type after switch

Tags: typescript

(Please feel free to edit the title if you can think of a better one.)

I have a discriminated union type below but even after doing a switch on the tag, I'm unable to get the type of another field. The code below has my questions in comments.

```
type AOrB = { type: 'A'; value: number } | { type: 'B'; value: string };

const fn = <T extends AOrB>(t: T) => {
  // t.type here is `'A' | 'B'`, which is correct.
  switch (t.type) {
    case 'A':
      // t.value here is `string | number` but should be `number`?
      break;
    case 'B':
      // t.value here is also `string | number` but should be `string`?
      break;
  }
};
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: It seems it can't work with generic type. It works without: `(t: AOrB) => {...}`.

Comment: Why generics used here?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it happens because of the implied typing of 'type'. Both 'A' and 'B' are strings, so just by looking at {type: string, value: ...} the compiler cannot tell A from B. So you might need smth like TypeA and TypeB, to keep them apart: {type: TypeA, value: number} | {type: TypeB, value: number} and switch with typeof.